# File is not created with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am using *Laravel Mix* but it is not creating one of the files specified. My *webpack.mix.js* looks like this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/mail.scss', 'resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css');
```

It does compile successfully, but the *default.css* file is not created. The *app.js* and *app.css* is working as it should. However, the *themes* folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out *Laravel Mix* uses the *public* folder as default. Meaning, my file was created (as were the directories) in the *public* folder. To "bypass" this, I added `../` to the path, like this:

```
    mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/mail.scss', '../resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the error messages in your question but I think its due to this:

You do not need to specify a path with a filename just use the path like this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/mail.scss', 'resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes');
```